# Jmeter - Auth token over time, troubles with evaluation of __time() function

Tags: authentication, jmeter

I have two Threads running in parallel, one responsible for the load testing, the other for generating Authentication token.

The problems I have are in this section:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skIBf.png)

Two if controllers checking basically the current time with the jmeter function ${__time(/1000,)}.
If the time + {delay time for next request} < current time = > time =current time and make request for the auth token.

The other controller's purpose is making the thread "sleep" for 30 seconds.

My problem is that it seems the if statement is executed only once and can not enter this if() and update my time property, hence only 1 token is requested and after time it will expire.

Do you have any idea why this if() statement is executed only once /Thread is infinite/ and how can I check for the current time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very possible to come up with the comprehensive solution without seeing your If Controllers conditions, so far I can only suggest checking all the variables and expressions using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script/) (including the functions used in the If Controllers)

Also be aware that

- [starting from JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)
- it is NOT recommended to reference [JMeter Functions and/or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like `${__time(/1000,)}` in Beanshell/Groovy scripts